# Java Regex capture multiple groups with groups containing others

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression which captures multiple groups, with some of them being contained in others. For instance, let's say I want to capture every 4-grams that follows a 'to' prefix:

```
input = "I want to run to get back on shape"
expectedOutput = ["run to get back", "get back on shape"]
```

In that case I would use this regex:

```
"to((?:[ ][a-zA-Z]+){4})"
```

But it only captures the first item in `expectedOutput` (with a space prefix but that's not the point).
This is quite easy to solve without regex, but I'd like to know if it is possible only using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a regex *overlapping mstrings*:

```
String s = "I want to run to get back on shape";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=\\bto\\b((?:\\s*[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+){4}))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim()); 
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/KEhZyO)

The regex [`(?=\bto\b((?:\s*[\p{L}\p{M}]+){4}))`](https://regex101.com/r/cI9tN5/1) checks each location in the string (since it is a zero width assertion) and looks for:

- `\bto\b` - a whole word `to`
- `((?:\s*[\p{L}\p{M}]+){4})` - Group 1 capturing 4 occurrences of

  - `\s*` zero or more whitespace(s)
  - `[\p{L}\p{M}]+` - one or more letters or diacritics

If you want to allow capturing fewer than 4 ngrams, use a `{0,4}` (or `{1,4}` to require at least one) greedy limiting quantifier instead of `{4}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for but I was not familiar yet with the zero-width positive lookahead `?=`

Answer (score 0):

It is the order of groups in `Regex`

```
1       ((A)(B(C)))   // first group (surround two other inside this)
2       (A)           // second group ()
3       (B(C))        // third group (surrounded one other group)
4       (C)           // forth group ()
```